# echo user input to terminal with php exec();

Tags: php, ubuntu, exec, echo, lamp

I just got a LAMP server this morning and i'm playing around with it. I have the php file:

```
<?php
    $input = $_REQUEST["input"];
    exec("echo " . $input);
?>
```

this has `$input` sent to it from an XMLHttpRequest on the actual index page. I have the server terminal open next to me but when I run this nothing happens. Is there way I can tell it to output that echo to my terminal?

Answer (score 0):

[`exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) returns a string of the last line output from the shell command, so you'll need to echo that output back in php

Use the [`passthru`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) function if you've got more than one line of output coming back

```
echo exec("echo " . $input);
```

You'll also want to be cognizant of variable expansion.

```
echo exec("echo \"$input\"");
```

Or prettier if you don't have nested escaped variables.

```
echo exec("echo '$input'");
```